# Retrieve Facebook full name and picture from profile url

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to make a website with text input for facebook profile url and after procceeding, there should be user's `name` and `profile image` shown.

I saw something like that here: http://hackfbaccountlive.com/hack_account.php
(No, I'm not making another fb hack.)

I have been trying for a couple of hours now, and I always need to log in, and it's not working as I want.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should go into detail about what you're trying to do, as it sounds suspicious (please do not create a hack site). That being said, this all public information that can be fetched with the following calls:

https://graph.facebook.com/[user_id]

https://graph.facebook.com/[user_id]/picture

https://graph.facebook.com/[profile_username]

https://graph.facebook.com/[profile_username]/picture

You can then use either the UID or the profile username to create the profile URL, which is just https://www.facebook.com/[username_or_id]